# Cambiar el Id principal de Vue.js (#app)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

necesito cambiar el id de entrada de Vue.js, de #app a otro valor. Si lo cambio en el archivo main.js, la aplicación deja de funcionar y no se que configuración debo tocar para tal cometido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de mi proyecto vue.js es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Cómo puedo realizar este cambio? Gracias.

Comment: El ID que pongas debe estar en el HTML, por favor comprueba que en tu index.nginx-debian.html tiene algún <div> con este ID.

Comment: No nada. Es muy extraño, porque no encuentro ningún otro archivo html.

Comment: Bien, pues primero comprueba que ese archivo *index.nginx-debian.html* es el archivo del que tira tu página: Prueba a meter un <h1> y ver que aparece, si es así, crea un <div> con ese id: <div id="app"></div>